# Extracting and placing keys from a p12 certificate

Tags: c, openssl, embedded, wifi, freertos

I have an embedded device which needs to connect to a router through wpa2 enterprise encryption.
I need to replace the default certificates in the code in the files `cacert.h , client-cert.h and client-key.h.`The keys and the certificates have to be so hard coded.
I have in my possession a `client.p12` file and its contents need to be distributed in these three files or any combination thereof.
Can anyone please tell how to extract the aforementioned keys from the`client.p12` file and after extraction which keys go where ?

Comment: Do you want solution through openssl tool or openssl API (via C program)?

Comment: I nned to segregate the certs from the p12 certificate though that is the main concern.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use openssl pkcs12 command. Please refer its [page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html).

To parse PKCS # 12 file (p12 file) into key and certificate, use following command

```
openssl pkcs12 -in client.p12 -out client.pem
```

client.pem will have certificates (as it also has chain of the certificate) and private key. All will be in PEM format. You can use some utility to read the content and separate them out as they begin with -----BEGIN.

It will also ask for the passphrase (for private key) and input passphrase for this p13 file.

If you only want to extract certificate, use following command.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in client.p12 -clcerts -out cert.pem
```

Here, cert.pem will have client certificate only.

I hope this would help you.

Comment: and can you also tell me about the client key

Comment: @dev-null_to_dev_full: The first command `openssl pkcs12 -in client.p12 -out client.pem` also outputs private key in client.pem. You can extract private key from the file.

Comment: And one last question how do you get something called a cacert from the same thing ??

Comment: In case of first command, it also outputs CA certificate. Otherwise, you can output CA certificate file into different file using -cacerts option.

Comment: I tried `openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -cacerts -out test.pem`. It worked for me. test.pem contains CA certificate.

Comment: I can generate the certs but they are not usable in my device.

Comment: What needs to your device? Is there any specific to your device like it needs into separate files or of some other formats?

Comment: I have already mentioned we need to fill in three files .I have mentioned inthe question.Those files are in C formats

Comment: Then why do not you copy the key from the file and paste it in header file manually? Or do you want to write a program which will read this file and generate the above mentioned header file? In that case, you can write a program in C using OpenSSL functions related to PKCS12/EVP_PKEY/X509.

Comment: Ihave already done the manual pasting but that has not woked so far and also dare i mention i have copy pasted the certs in all manners possible decryption encryption .I was after it for two whole days!

Comment: Is there any chain of CA certificates?

Comment: NO only one Ca is there]